# Multi-cell LiPo charging while still powering system?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, control-system, charging, lipo

I'm working on a control system PCB design that's powered by 2, 3.7V LiPo batteries in series to achieve a higher voltage output. I would like to integrate charging via a mini-B USB connector with simultaneous powering but am unsure how to do this. So far I have looked into a similar solution as seen [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-cell-lipo-charging/simple-balance-charger), which manages charging and balancing well but cannot power the device when charging. Is there another way to do this? Can I charge in series and treat the 2 cells as a single unit in this configuration? [image] Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!